# Problem with upgraded project from iphone sdk3.2 to work on sdk4.0

Tags: objective-c, ios4

I had a application that was written for iphone SDK3.2 and now I want that application to be upgraded to full fill multi tasking...
I just compiled it to SDK4.0 actually it has to get upgraded and when the home button is pressed it should 1st go to applicationWillResignActive and then it should goto
 applicationDidEnterBackground but my application is not calling applicationDidEnterBackground but it is calling applicationWillTerminate...
Should I need to add any code to prevent this to happen if so, Please any one help me in solving this...

Waiting for reply...

~Raviraja

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to setup the app to build as follows:

- Base SDK: iPhone Device 4.0
- iPhone OS Deployment Target: iPhone OS 3.0

They are two separate settings when in the Project > Edit Project Settings section of Xcode.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

In your 'Info.plist', add 'Application does not run in background' and make sure the checkbox is NOT checked.

[Source](http://www.davidortinau.com/blog/2010/06/)

Comment: Actually Iam not getting "Application does not run in background" in my info.plist file...